# JS - dynamically selecting video coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

Let's say I have the following video:

```
<video id ="vid" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
var width = vid.videoWidth; //320
var height = vid.videoHeight; //176
</script>
```

now, it's width & height are 320:176 - it could be anything though.

Now, the thing I'd like to do is say the user selects a certain point upon the video, as he moves left/right/up/down a square dynamically forms, covering the entire area that the user has chosen(usually when a user clicks on the video itself it stop, in our case - no). I'd like the square to be seen.

it works just like you choose the rectangle in windows paint.
so as he releases the mouse LM button(meaning the square is complete),
a new js object is formed with the following:
width: x, height: y, top: z, left: s

so, this square is supposed to point at specific coordinates,
 which are essentially a square.

I am just trying to select a precise piece of the video. for starters I'll just need that square.

So, how can I do such thing? do I need to manipulate a canvas? any js library?
Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a quick-start on grabbing a sub-rectangle of a video frame using html5 canvas.**

A video element can be an image source for a canvas element. To "play" the video on a canvas you create an animation loop and continuously draw current video frames onto the canvas. There are many tutorials on how to draw video onto canvas -- [here's one example tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas).

```
context.drawImage(vid,0,0);
```

Listen for canvas.mousedown events. Then pause the video and let the user select a rectangular portion of the canvas. Use the `vid.pause` method to pause the video. Also cancel the animation loop so the canvas displays a static frame from the video.

```
vid.pause();
```

When the video is paused and canvas is static, let the user draw a selection rectangle with their mouse.

```
// on mousemove ...
function draw(){
    // refresh canvas by redrawing the paused video frame onto the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(vid,0,0);
    // stroke a rectangle based on the users starting & current mouse position
    ctx.strokeRect(startX,startY,mouseX-startX,mouseY-startY);
}
```

On mouseup, create a second canvas and draw the user's selected sub-image onto the second canvas. If you need to export the sub-image, you can create an img element from the second canvas.

Example code and a Demo showing how to let the user select a rectangular portion of a canvas and export it to an img element. The canvas in this demo shows a static image. You will draw your video element onto the canvas instead.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY,mouseX,mouseY;

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/faces1.png";
function start(){
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  draw();
  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
}

function draw(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  if(!isDown){return;}
  ctx.strokeRect(startX,startY,mouseX-startX,mouseY-startY);
}

function capture(){
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
  var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
  var x=startX;
  var y=startY;
  var w=mouseX-startX;
  var h=mouseY-startY;
  c.width=w;
  c.height=h;
  cctx.drawImage(canvas,x,y,w,h,0,0,w,h);
  var img=new Image();
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  img.src=c.toDataURL();
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;        

  // create a cropped image
  capture();
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  isDown=false;
  draw();       
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!isDown){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  draw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag to select an area. Release to create a clipped img.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: First off this is good example, my problem is with toDataURL, I was already aware of it and the problem it causes. That's why I stated that the only thing I really wanted was just being able to draw a rectangle and then upon release, a new js object is created with cords that represent a rectangle and it's location. I will look further into your example and try to extract what I need.

Comment: Oh, and is there a way to fill that rec with water color? transparent, that is.

Comment: Yes, you can use rgba to fill the rect with semi-transparent color. `fillStyle='rgba(135,206,250,0.50)` Good luck with your project!